# Rotate parent so child looks in a certain direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, camera-calibration, calibration

The object heiarchy is as so:

```
Player
   - OVRCameraRig
       - TrackingSpace
           - CentralEyeAnchor (Camera)
```

By default the player is initially facing towards the right area, but since this in VR someone might want to calibrate or "home" the player so the camera faces the scene without needing to face that direction in real life. This is using Oculus Quest, so I basically want the player rotation offset to change so camera is looking at the scene.

Script is attached to Player, with vrCamera as CentralEyeAnchor:

```
        Quaternion quat = Quaternion.Inverse(rotationOffset) * vrCamera.transform.rotation;

        Vector3 euler = quat.eulerAngles;
        euler.x = 0;
        euler.z = 0;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(euler);

        rotationOffset = transform.rotation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the relative rotation `relativeRot` between the camera and the player, such that `playerRotation == cameraRotation * relativeRot`.

By multiplying both sides on the left by `Inverse(cameraRotation)`, we know that then `Inverse(cameraRotation) * playerRotation == relativeRot`:

```
Quaternion relativeRot = Quaternion.Inverse(vrCamera.transform.rotation) * transform.rotation;
```

Then, determine the rotation you'd like your camera to have. Perhaps use `Quaternion.LookRotation` with the direction you'd like the camera to look:

```
Vector3 desiredCameraLookAtPoint;
Vector3 desiredCameraLookDirection = desiredCameraLookAtPoint - vrCamera.transform.position;
Quaternion desiredCameraRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredCameraLookDirection);
```

Finally, solve for and assign the player's rotation using the relative rotation and the desired camera rotation:

```
transform.rotation = desiredCameraRot * relativeRot;
```

Comment: Great answer! I also zero-ed out x and z from the quaternion result, and put the OVRCameraRig position to zero. Works great!

Comment: Be careful editing the components of a quaternion... It could lead to unexpected situations if the user does something like tilt their head. Did it work without zeroing out the components?  If you need to fine tune the direction the camera's `up` is pointing, you should be able to use that as the 2nd (optional) argument to `LookRotation`...

Comment: It didn't work without zeroing out x and z, meaning it was pointing all over the place with the code unchanged. I should clarify that I used euler angles to zero out x & z and used Quaternion.Euler on that result to set the transform.rotation. However, when the head is tilted up there are some results that put the camera in the wrong position.